# Significado da expressão n %= 100

Tags: c

Tenho estudado C e me deparei com um problema bem difícil que depois de muito tentar, desisti e fui buscar um algoritmo pronto na internet pra estudar em cima dele, mas a expressão n %= 100 eu não consegui compreender de jeito nenhum. Eu procurei em vários sites de programação e matemática mas tudo o que encontrava era que o símbolo da porcentagem em meio a dois números inteiros retornava o resto da divisão, e isso eu já sabia, mas e quando tem uma igualdade junto?

Se ajudar o problema é o 1018 do módulo iniciante do URI.

Eis o código que estou estudando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 100,00\n", n/100);
    n %= 100;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 50,00\n", n/50);
    n %= 50;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 20,00\n", n/20);
    n %= 20;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 10,00\n", n/10);
    n %= 10;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 5,00\n", n/5);
    n %= 5;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 2,00\n", n/2);
    n %= 2;
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 1,00\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compreende que `n % 100` é o resto da divisão de `n` por 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O operador `%` (**módulo**) retorna o resto da divisão entre dois números inteiros. Quando encontramos uma expressão como `x = 5 % 2;` isso quer dizer que `x` receberá o resto da divisão de `5` por `2`, isto é, `x` passará armazenar o valor `1`. Matematicamente, **`5`≡`x`mod`2`**.

É importante notar que `%` só opera sobre números inteiros, logo qualquer tentativa de utilizá-lo com operandos de outro tipo, `float` por exemplo, resultará em erro.

Já a expressão `n %= 100;` é uma forma de [syntactic sugar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A7%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1tico) equivalente a `n = n % 100;` e, entre outras formas, pode ser reescrita como:

```
aux = n % 100;
n = aux;
```

Alguns outros exemplos de syntatic sugar em linguagens baseadas em C são:

```
a += 5;    // a = a + 5
b -= 4;    // b = b - 4
c *= 3;    // c = c * 3
d /= 2;    // d = d / 2
```

Comment: Creio que seja interessante falar sobre o operador módulo `%` para clarificar ao AP o que está acontecendo. Também tenho algumas observações quando aos operadores de incremento/decremento pós-fixos, pois não é exatamente isso que acontece quando usado em expressões

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, não julguei necessário explicar o operador `%` pois já existe, na própria pergunta, uma breve descrição do que ele faz. Quanto aos operadores pós-fixados, você tem toda a razão!

Comment: Acho relevante ao menos mencionar um pouco sobre o resto da divisão, pois as respostas não são apenas para o autor da pergunta, e sim para todos os futuros visitantes (e como você notou, está apenas brevemente descrito na pergunta). O resto da resposta me parece bom, bem formatado e bem ilustrado. Está no caminho certo.